# C word count histogram application returns no output

Tags: c, output, console-application, histogram

I'm trying to solve K&R C exercise 1-13 by creating a horizontally-oriented histogram that measures the frequency of words of different lengths in the user's input.  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

int a, b, c, d;                                 //array_position, word_length, getchar(), word_count
int y[10];                                      //array representing word lengths from 1-10 letters

b =  0;                                         //word_length initializes with a zero value
a = 1;                                          //array_position initializes with a value of one (no words contain zero characters)


for(y[a] = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF;){         //current array position initializes with a zero value, and c initializes as the current input character
    if(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')      //if c is anything other than a blank, newline or tab
        ++b;                                     //increment the word_length by one
    else                                        //otherwise
        ++a;                                    //increment the array_position by one
        b = 0;                                  //and reset the word_length to zero
}

a = 1;                                          //reset the array_position to one

do{
    if(y[a] > 0){                               //if current array_position holds a value greater than 0
        printf("%i",a);                         //print the name of the array_position (1,2,3...)
        for(d = 0; d < y[a]; ++d){              //reset the word_length--if the word_length is less than the value contained in the current array position, increment the word length by one
            putchar('-');                       //print a dash and re-evaluate the condition
        }
        if(d == y[a]){                          //when the word_length is equal to the value contained in the current array position
            putchar('-');                       //print a final dash
            putchar('\n');                      //and a newline
        }
    }
    ++a;                                        //increment the array position by one
}while(a > 11);                                 //repeat until the current array position is 11
}
```

The code is meant to produce a very simple chart that would look something like this, sorting words of lengths from 1-10 characters:

```
1---
2----------
3-----
4--
```

and so on.  It would also omit any lengths that are not represented by one or more words from the input.  However, the code as it appears above returns *no* output *at all*, and I've been working on this problem for three days.

What am I unable to see that is preventing my code from producing the desired output?

Comment: `do {...} while(a > 11)` should be `for (a=1;a<=10;a++)`, but note that the array needs to be declared as `int y[11]` so that the valid indexes in the array are 0 through 10. And you need to fully initialize the array before using it. Also, be sure to check that the word length is `<= 10` before updating the array. Many words are longer than 10 letters.

Comment: The loop ought to print at least once but stops the first time `while (a > 11)` is encountered. Are you sure it should not be something like `a < 11` instead? (The print statements depend on the `if` - apparently you never get there.)

Comment: Are you missing `{ braces }` in your first `else` block? The way you have it, `b` will be reset to `0` anyway. And why are you following an obsolete tutorial that has `main()` and not `int main(void)`?

Comment: Why use such cryptic variable names that you need a comment to explain what each variable is? Why not name your variables `array_position`, `word_length`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
a = 1;                                          //reset the array_position to one
do{
    if(y[a] > 0){                               //if current array_position holds a value greater than 0
        printf("%i",a);                         //print the name of the array_position (1,2,3...)
        for(d = 0; d < y[a]; ++d){              //reset the word_length--if the word_length is less than the value contained in the current array position, increment the word length by one
            putchar('-');                       //print a dash and re-evaluate the condition
        }
        if(d == y[a]){                          //when the word_length is equal to the value contained in the current array position
            putchar('-');                       //print a final dash
            putchar('\n');                      //and a newline
        }
    }
    ++a;                                        //increment the array position by one
}while(a > 11);
```

you need to check `while (a < 11)` instead of `while (a > 11)`

And, (as pointed out by @WeatherVane):

```
if(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')      //if c is anything other than a blank, newline or tab
    ++b;                                     //increment the word_length by one
else                                        //otherwise
    ++a;                                    //increment the array_position by one
    b = 0;
```

looks suspicious, did you forget the braces around the second block?

```
if(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')      //if c is anything other than a blank, newline or tab
    ++b;                                     //increment the word_length by one
else {                                       //otherwise
    ++a;                                    //increment the array_position by one
    b = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two main issues:

First, as was mentioned before, your `do..while` loop should be checking for `a < 11` instead of `a > 11`.

The second problem is in your first `for` loop:

```
for(y[a] = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF;){     
    if(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')  
        ++b;                                
    else                                    
        ++a;                                
        b = 0;                              
}
```

Besides the missing braces around the `else` part, you're never assigning anything to the elements of `y` except for position 1 when you first enter the loop.

You need to initialize the array elements to 0, then you need to increment `y[b]` instead of `a`:

```
for (d=0;d<10;d++) {
    y[d] = 0;
}
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t') {
        ++b;                                
    } else {
        ++y[b];
        b = 0;    
    }                          
}
```